# dnn_superres in opencv 4.5.5 C++ Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, resolution

I want to implement Super Resolution in OpenCV C++ using Visual Studio but it gives error `Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/dnn_superres.hpp': No such file or directory`

My opencv2 folder doesn't contains `dnn_superres.hpp` file.
So how to implement super resolution.
I am using the below version:

```
OpenCV version : 4.5.5
Major version : 4
Minor version : 5
Subminor version : 5
```

Comment: Did you build and install opencv_contrib module?

Comment: No I didn't did that, how to do it in Visual Studio?

Comment: the following link explains for 4.1 but the procedure is same for 4.5.x too
https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/

Comment: I did follow the procedure accordingly but it gives error while build

Comment: It worked using ```https://swallow-incubate.com/archives/blog/20200508/``` this link

Comment: glad I could be of help